Aliens are invading Earth, humans are fighting back. There's one human who can transform into an alien
I've been looking for this movie since I was a kid, and I haven't had any luck. I don't remember anything about it aside from the final scene:
The main character is a human who can transform into an alien.  I think the alien is disguised as human, and his friend doesn't know he's an alien.
He's fighting against an Alien invasion of Earth.  In the last scene, another human (I don't know who he/she is, but I think it's the main character's best friend) has shot the main character while in alien form.  The main character then dies, and changes back into human form as he dies.
The movie was probably a product of Hollywood, USA.  If I remember anything else, I'll edit the question to include details.

Hi. Do you remember the movie's approximate year\decade of release?

Can you describe any of the actors, either in appearance or something unique about how they talked?  What did the aliens look like?  When did you watch this movie (approximate year would be great)?  Any technology ie: ray guns, UFOs) that you can remember how they looked?  Every detail you can think of would help.

@Walt I don't know what year/decade is released, I bet is from 2008/2009.

@Steve-O I'm just know the appearance of the aliens looks like, he's like  an alien usually, they technology is UFO's shooting everything in below of Earth, and use ray guns too, to attack humans.

@JanDoggen I think your film is little revelant at my question, I'll research for that film by the way, and search everything to found my question through your film.

it's not dream catcher by Stephen King is it? A good Alien is hiding as a human, at the end it turns back into an Alien to fight a bad Alien...

Sounds somewhat reminiscent of the X Files episode with the grey/shapeshifter alien baseball player, The Unnatural.

Skyline ? I think there was a scene with the transformation involving gunfire/injury. The ending has a different transformation (described on the wiki). Except it's 2010, I remember release was same time as first half of the Harry Potter finale. If not the correct match, may help for process of elimination.

The answer is District 9 guys, he's been answering my question. So?, it's done, thank you guys.

The answer is District 9, from IMDb

An extraterrestrial race forced to live in slum-like conditions on Earth suddenly finds a kindred spirit in a government agent who is exposed to their biotechnology. 

Identified by Jan Doggen in comment.

did I make a wrong mistake?, why -1? :'(

You know the answer, of course, but good answers to identify-this-film questions provide explanations of how the proposed movie matches the description in the question.

@JamesMcLeod Oh I see, sorry for the wrong, I'm new here, so I really need more rule in here.

We were all new once. Take the tour, read a few high-voted questions and answers, and you'll pick it up in no time. I think the down vote was unnecessarily harsh.

@JamesMcLeod I'll take the tour right now, thank you for your information btw.
